# batch - convert repeatative code to loop?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file where I'm creating a number of shortcuts like this:

```
SET VBFILE=createshortcut.vbs
SET INSTALLPATH=%userprofile%\desktop
SET NETWORKPATH=I:\Program Files\app\Exec

SET TARGET_A=%NETWORKPATH%\myapp-CS.exe
SET LNKNAME_A=The name of the app CS

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE% 
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("sLinkFile = "%INSTALLPATH%\%LNKNAME_A%.lnk"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.TargetPath = "%TARGET_A%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.Arguments = """) DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%NETWORKPATH%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.Save") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%

CSCRIPT %INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
DEL %INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%

SET TARGET_B=%NETWORKPATH%\myapp-BD.exe
SET LNKNAME_B=The name of the app BD

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE% 
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("sLinkFile = "%INSTALLPATH%\%LNKNAME_A%.lnk"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.TargetPath = "%TARGET_B%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.Arguments = """) DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%NETWORKPATH%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.Save") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%

CSCRIPT %INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
DEL %INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
```

Is there a way to reduce the repeatative code and put it in GOTO statements or a for-loop?

With GOTO, I can't figure out a way to return back to where the GOTO was called. In a for-loop, I can't figure out a good way to overwrite the variables with new values in each iteration.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `call` as a substitute for `goto` which will automatically return to the calling code when the function is finished.

```
@echo off
echo Starting batch file
call :RepeatFunction
echo Finished

:RepeatFunction
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE% 
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("sLinkFile = "%INSTALLPATH%\%LNKNAME_A%.lnk"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.TargetPath = "%TARGET_A%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.Arguments = """) DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   '   oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%NETWORKPATH%"") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%B IN ("   oLink.Save") DO ECHO %%B>>%INSTALLPATH%\%VBFILE%
```